# Literature for modal logic and coalgebras (focused on logic and category theory)

Tags: logic, category-theory, modal-logic, coalgebras

I've been looking for literature that focuses on coalgebras and modal logic. But all literature I can find is mostly related to automata theory, or otherwise takes heavy influence from computer science, which doesn't really interest me that much.

I want to learn about modal logic and its connection to category theory and coalgebras from mathematical perspective, without reading about modeling theoretical machines. Is there some literature that you would recommend?

Comment: Jacobs' book on coalgebra is the only place where I've seen both concepts together; is that also the place where you found too much automata theory?

Comment: @fosco I'll check it out, I haven't seen that book yet. It seems a bit less automata-theoretic than the ones I've seen.